# What is the correct way to extend object preserving prototype

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a shallow copy of an object but preserve its prototype. `angular.extend` seems to lose prototype when extending object. How can I extend an object so that the new object has the same prototype as original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to do so is to additionally use `setPrototypeOf` like this:

```
var copy = angular.extend(original);
Object.setPrototypeOf(copy, original.getPrototypeOf(original))
```

Also, `extend` drops `getters` and `setters` defined through `Object.defineProperty` on an `original`.

Answer (score 0):

It might help your problem, Please review it

[http://www.tothenew.com/blog/angularjs-copy-vs-extend/](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/angularjs-copy-vs-extend/)

Comment: no mentioning of prototype in the link you mentioned